# How to update state so that my timer will run after video load

Tags: reactjs, video, react-state

I am newbie on react. I am bit stuck in problem and need to know some pointers regarding state update.

PROBLEM: I am making the video on load and add the skip button for removing the video from screen. Video will be played through HTML  under the modal. Problem is my video load in 2 or 3 sec after the page refresh and modal will open prior to load video. I have set the timer from 5 seconds which is in reverse format like 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, skip

But due to slow/late video load, timer run in background and in front side when video display sometime it sees 3, 2, 1, skip

What I am looking for is when my video start load then only my timer function trigger.

I have tried onLoad(), onStart() to update the flag state from false to true and on componentDidMount -> load the page according to the state but not getting luck

This is my code:

```
export default class FullScreenAds extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFullPageVideoModalEnabled: false,
      timerForVideo: 7,
      isDisabled: true,
    };
  },
  async componentDidMount() {
    const uuid = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    let getUserSession = localStorage.getItem("gid");
    if (getUserSession === null || getUserSession.length < 1) {
      localStorage.setItem("gid", uuid);
    }
    this.setState({
      isFullPageVideoModalEnabled: true,
      getSession: getUserSession
    })
    this.startTimer()
  },
  async startTimer() {
    // await sleep(3000);
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      const { timerForVideo } = this.state

      if (timerForAds > 0) {
        this.setState(({ timerForVideo }) => ({
          timerForVideo: timerForVideo - 1
        }))
      }
      if (timerForAds === 0) {
        this.setState({ isDisabled: false })
        clearInterval(this.timer)
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      // run the modal based on state and load the video
    <video  width="100%" height="auto" autoPlay playsInline loop>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="video/src/url" />
    </video>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference with `React.createRef()` and attach the reference to the video, then listen for the onplay event on the video and start the timer when the onplay event fires:

Try this:

```js
export default class FullScreenAds extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.videoRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      isFullPageVideoModalEnabled: false,
      timerForVideo: 7,
      isDisabled: true,
    };
  },
  async componentDidMount() {
    const uuid = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    let getUserSession = localStorage.getItem("gid");
    if (getUserSession === null || getUserSession.length < 1) {
      localStorage.setItem("gid", uuid);
    }
    this.setState({
      isFullPageVideoModalEnabled: true,
      getSession: getUserSession
    })
    this.videoRef.current.onplay = () => this.startTimer();
  },
  async startTimer() {
    // await sleep(3000);
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      const { timerForVideo } = this.state

      if (timerForAds > 0) {
        this.setState(({ timerForVideo }) => ({
          timerForVideo: timerForVideo - 1
        }))
      }
      if (timerForAds === 0) {
        this.setState({ isDisabled: false })
        clearInterval(this.timer)
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      // run the modal based on state and load the video
    <video ref={this.videoRef} width="100%" height="auto" autoPlay playsInline loop>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="video/src/url" />
    </video>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @PetersonCode, Thanks for the interaction. I have tried your code but timer will not reduce from 7 to 6. It stuck in 7. Renamed <video ref={this.myRef}> to <video ref={this.videoRef}>

Comment: This error I am getting on browser console: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onplay')"

Comment: Hmm not sure why is that. The reference should be attached by the time the component renders and should not be null. Can you try using a function component with hooks instead as shown in the updated answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try using functional component with hooks.

Something like this:

```js
export const FullScreenAds = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    isFullPageVideoModalEnabled: false,
    timerForVideo: 7,
    isDisabled: true,
  });
  const videoRef = React.useRef();
  const timerRef = React.useRef();

  const startTimer = () => {
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      const { timerForVideo } = state;

      if (timerForAds > 0) {
        setState({
          ...state,
          timerForVideo: state.timerForVideo - 1,
        });
      }
      if (timerForAds === 0) {
        setState({ ...state, isDisabled: false });
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const uuid = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    let getUserSession = localStorage.getItem("gid");

    if (getUserSession === null || getUserSession.length < 1) {
      localStorage.setItem("gid", uuid);
    }

    setState({
      ...state,
      isFullPageVideoModalEnabled: true,
      getSession: getUserSession,
    });

    videoRef.current.onplay = startTimer;

    return clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <video
      ref={this.videoRef}
      width="100%"
      height="auto"
      autoPlay
      playsInline
      loop
    >
      <source type="video/mp4" src="video/src/url" />
    </video>
  );
};
```